# Display wrong Result in different Excel sheet Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, worksheet, xlsxwriter

I wish to have 1 python file that can display the results in different Excel sheet, now I able to list out 3 tabs with 3 worksheets,but for/if loop at second sheet that show me empty result. I able to get the results correct in first sheet but not second sheet.

```
for module in data:
#Go to first sheet
str1 = ''.join(module)
if len(module)<102:
  pass
else:
   worksheet1.write_row(row, col, module)
   row += 1

if str1.isupper():
    pass
else:
    worksheet1.write_row(row, col, module)
    row += 1


#Go to second sheet
#Show empty result in second sheet
MY_MODULE=module[0].split('_') #Module Name
if 1<len(MY_MODULE)<4: #Field Number in Module Name
  pass
else:
  worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
  row += 1

if len(MY_MODULE[0])==3: #Length in Scrum Field
  pass
else:
  worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
  row += 1

if MY_MODULE[0]in ('TPI','SCN','ARR','FUN','MIO','CLK','HTD','SIO','PTH'): #Name in Scrum Field
   pass
else:
   worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
   row += 1

if 2<len(MY_MODULE[1])<9: #Length in Module Name Field
   pass
else:
   worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
   row += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(MY_MODULE[0])==3: #Length in Scrum Field
  pass
else:
  worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
  row += 1

if MY_MODULE[0]in ('TPI','SCN','ARR','FUN','MIO','CLK','HTD','SIO','PTH'): #Name in Scrum Field
   pass
else:
   worksheet2.write_row(row, col, MY_MODULE)
   row += 1
```

Here two if conditions are actually same. Because in last if condition length of all given input string is 3. So you are given two same if conditions and you are printing same result in two times at else condition.